# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser' not found in

Tags: php, keyword, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use google_ads_api to generate keywords idea.
I found an error when I execute generateKeywordsIdeas.php file.

> PS C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api> php GenerateKeywordIdeas.php
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api\GenerateKeywordIdeas.php:67
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api\GenerateKeywordIdeas.php(212): Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Planning\GenerateKeywordIdeas::main()
>   #1 {main}
>     thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api\GenerateKeywordIdeas.php on line 67
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api\GenerateKeywordIdeas.php:67
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api\GenerateKeywordIdeas.php(212): Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Planning\GenerateKeywordIdeas::main()
>   #1 {main}
>     thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ads_api\GenerateKeywordIdeas.php on line 67

Here is file structure of my project

[image]

Why this error happens..? can anybody explain..?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your missing required files from the 'examples' directory? They're excluded from the ZIP when you download the package from github. You can grab them here:

https://downgit.github.io/#/home?url=https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/tree/master/examples